# Calculation result: -1.#IND000000000000 in Visual C++ Express 2010

Tags: visual-c++

I got a wrong result in an equation that I used in my following code

```
dQ_rad = 0.7 * 5.67e-8 * rotor.dRotorOuterArea[iAxle] * (dT1*dT1*dT1*dT1 - dT2*dT2*dT2*dT2);
```

All the variables are declared as DOUBLE, where

```
rotor.dRotorOuterArea[iAxle] = 0.052986887100527499
dT1 = 0;
dT2 = 293.0;
```

dQ_rad will get the result -1.#IND000000000000, which I really don't understand. 
Then I used the same equation in "QuickWatch", the correct result can be seen as follows (!?)

```
0.7 * 5.67e-8 * rotor.dRotorOuterArea[iAxle] * (dT1*dT1*dT1*dT1 - dT2*dT2*dT2*dT2) -15.499582013297069  double
```

Does anyone know how this error happened and how I can avoid this kind of error?

I use VC Express 2010 and the code is compiled using default MS C-Compiler.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you get the same result with debug and release builds ?

Comment: #IND is a silly CRT debug, it should read #INF.  You'll get infinity from dividing by zero.  Post a code snippet that we can try ourselves.

Comment: Should be a difference if I use "Release" configuration? because I always use "Debug" mode

Comment: I think it was not a division by zero problem because there is no division in the code ....

Answer (score 1):

`-1.#IND000000000000` is Microsoft's  representation of `NaN`. NaN can result due to a variety of operations, such as `sqrt(-1.0)`, `log(-1.0)`, `0/0`, `0*INF`, `INF/INF`. `NaN` is also propagated, so any operation on a double with value `NaN` will resut in a `NaN`. The following article provides more information about this (and other floating point states), and may be valuable in debugging this problem:

http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce your error in a trivial test case so it is difficult to provide more detailed information:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double rotor = 0.052986887100527499;
    double dT1 = 0;
    double dT2 = 293.0;

    double dQ_rad = 0.7 * 5.67e-8 * rotor * (dT1*dT1*dT1*dT1 - dT2*dT2*dT2*dT2);
    //fprintf(stderr, "%.12lf\n", dQ_rad);

    return 0;
}
```

One option you could try is to split your `dQ_rad` calculation into multiple steps, and verify the result of each operation to make sure it is not `NaN`. Something like:

```
double dQ_rad1 = 0.7 * 5.67e-18;
double dQ_rad2 = dQ_rad1 * rotor;
double dQ_rad3 = dT1*dT1*dT1*dT1;
double dQ_rad4 = dT2*dT2*dT2*dT2;
double dQ_rad5 = dQ_rad3 - dQ_rad4;
double dQ_rad = dQ_rad2 * dQ_rad5;
```

This may help to isolate which part of the calculation is resulting in a `NaN`.

Comment: Hi，thanks for your answer. At least on my computer with VS Express 2010 using a C compiler the error is reproducible, that is exactly what I don't understand. 

Also first idea came to my mind was to split the formular into separate parts to debug. But what I wrote here above is just simple part of a huge file full of this kind of calcations. Debugging all the formulars is very difficult. 

Right now I suspect that whether the error is coming from the C compiler. There is a config option in VC Express to choose between C and C++. I am wondering whether using C++ Compiler can solve the issue.

Comment: I tried the example above in both C and C++ and was not able to reproduce a failure. Since some floating point calculations can be affected by compiler options, you may also want to show the command-line your using to compile your application. You may also want to investigate whether the processor you're using has any known problems related to floating point calculations.

Comment: Hi, right now I solved the problem. It was a missed function-call which results to this problem.